# Joomla - Linking a hidden page on my site that links only to newsletter.

Tags: html, joomla

Silly question, but I was wondering if there is a way to link a part of my newsletter (which is set up through my sites Joomla AcyMailing system) to a new page that is not visible to users unless they click on the link in my newsletter.  i.e. I want to send my customers a newsletter that links not just to pages on the site, but also to lets say a page with only a printable coupon.)  I understand the links to the parts that are visible on my page and how the tags are suppose to go, but I just don't get setting up a different page (or maybe an article and or category) without being visible on the main page.  The ultimate goal is for customers to be able to click on the "feature coupon" link/image in the newsletter and go to a simple page with nothing but the image.)  I hope I put this in the right section of this site.  If I didn't, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new category then an article with that category type, and ensure that it is published but "Featured" is set to 'No', then you should be able to link directly to it, without it appearing on your front page.

To find the correct URL to link to the article from your newsletter, there is a good thread over [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=686763)

Comment: I did what you were talking about, but I can't see to find the field where I can set the URL to link to my newsletter.